# How to launch entity framework project

Tags: entity-framework, iis, installation

I am completely unaware of EF, but got an EF project from a candidate. Couldn't open it in Visual Studio 2010 and want at least to run it in IIS to review if neccessary functionality has been done.

How to install it in IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework 6 is not supported by VS 2010, please check that this is not your problem.

Ensure your IIS server has .NET 4 for EF 5 and below, or .NET 4.5 if using EF 6

You will probably also need to edit the supplied connection string to point at a valid database server.